# How do you find the value of theta in this example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My problem says to find the measure of each acute angle $\theta$ to the nearest degree.

$$\large\cos\theta = 0.2249$$

Comment: Basically you have to apply the inverse function of $\cos$ on both sides ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_function ) the problem is that $\cos$ is not one-to-one therefore you have to specify the interval of theta you are looking for.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ccos%5Ctheta%20%3D%200.2249&t=crmtb01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two places on the unit circle corresponding to values of $\theta$ satisfy your equation:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The inverse cosine (or arccosine) function will give us the one that's in the range $[0,\pi]$: $$\arccos(0.2249)\approx1.34396.$$
The other location can be described by the opposite of that value.  We can also add any integer multiple of $2\pi$ to either of these values and still be at the same place on the unit circle, with the same value for cosine, so: $$\theta=\pm\arccos(0.2249)+2\pi k,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

---

*edit* Oops, you only asked for the acute one, and in degrees.  The arccosine function gives the unique result in $[0^\circ,180^\circ]$, and acute angles are in $(0^\circ,90^\circ)$, so if there is an acute angle, it will be $\theta=\arccos(0.2249)\approx77^\circ$.